# Typescript cannot access static class member in ngFor loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to practice Typescript and ran into an issue that seems to either be an Angular problem or I'm at least getting conflicting feedback

In my Angular view, I am trying to loop over a static array of fighters in a class `Roster`. Here is the class definition:

```
export class Roster {
  static Fighters: Array<Fighter> = [
    ...
  ]
}
```

In my view, I am trying to loop over the predefined `Fighter`s with:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let fighter of Roster.Fighters; let i = index">
```

However I get an error here, with the message:

> Property 'Fighters' does not exist on type 'Roster'. Did you mean to access the static member 'Roster.Fighters' instead?ngtsc(2576)

This is confusing because of already accessed the fighters array in the class itself, here's the other member of my `Roster` class

```
export class Roster {
  static fighterLookup(fighterId: number): Fighter {
    console.log(Roster.Fighters[fighterId]);
  }
  ...
}
```

And in my component, I've simply assigned a Roster variable to the class definition:

```
export class AppComponent {
  Roster: Roster = Roster;
}
```

So I can access the list of fighters with `Roster.Fighters` in the typescript file but I can't do so in the ngFor loop? What am I missing? Do I need to define it some other way in my component to be able to access the static array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason of such behavior is because in typescript class you always has access to static method by the name of the class (It's `Roster` in your case), it's part of javascript language

In the angular template you don't have access to class itself, just instance of this class(it's like `new Roster` all the time)

In this case you can add some getter to the class:

```
export class Roster {
  static Fighters: Array<Fighter> = [
    ...
  ]

  get FightersView() {
     return Roster.Fighters;
  }

}
```

Comment: Ahh of course, this makes a lot of sense thank you! I think I was too distracted by all the new Typescript syntax